# multiple tables creation at runtime

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

i need to create a standalone database app using java and HSQL, the constructor of the app creates the database and 2 tables.I wrote the following:

```
        Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection(
        jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\\prod  \\prod,"SA","");
        Statement statement1=connection.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        statement1.executeQuery(query1);
        statement1.close();
        Statement statement2=connection.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
        statement2.executeQuery(query2);
        statement2.close();
        connection.close();
```

aftre running the application, only the first statement has been executed and one table has been created without any SQL exceptions. any help.............best ergards

Comment: What is inside `query1` and `query2`?

Comment: String query1="CREATE TABLE table1(date Date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, field_A DOUBLE NOT NULL,field_B DOUBLE NOT NULL)";

Comment: String query2="CREATE TABLE table2(date Date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, field_C DOUBLE NOT NULL,field_D DOUBLE NOT NULL)";

Comment: As your full code is not included so out of curiosity, why do you need to have `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);` if you are creating tables? And do the closing of connection and statement in finally block of your `try .. catch..finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `executeQuery(text)` for CREATE TABLE and other data definition statements.

Use `executeUpdate(text)` instead.